# Codeigniter vs MVC

Tags: php, codeigniter, oop

"CodeIgniter has a fairly loose approach to MVC" is that mean other frame works have very good approach to MVC?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CodeIgniter is primarily a [Model View Controller](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) Framework. MVC, itself, is an Object Oriented [Design Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_design_pattern).

The MVC Pattern fits web applications well. The purpose of a framework like CodeIgniter is to handle the mechanics of MVC for you, so that you can spend your time working on the functionality of the actual application.

You can continue to use whatever OOP patterns you were using before and integrate them with the CodeIgniter framework. However, using a framework will always add certain constraints and limitations to your overall design. You'll need to use CodeIgniter's models, views, and controllers for example.

CodeIgniter also [provides many utilities and features](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/overview/features.html) to help with other aspects of developing the application, however, you aren't forced to use them.

This is a fairly broad question, so this is a fairly broad answer :)